# add operator within a variable in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how is it possible to use an add operator within a string.
I have the following function:

```
var point_1_x = 50;
var point_2_y = 100;

array[0].animate({path:"M, "+point_1_x+", "+point_1_y+"", 5, '<>');}
```

but I want to use `var point_1_x` and add an integer to it. How would be the correct syntax to do this.

```
array[0].animate({path:"M, "+point_1_x+500+", "+point_1_y+"", 5, '<>');}
```

does not seem to work.

Cheers

Comment: 99%: +parseInt(parseInt(point_1_x)+Number(500))+

Comment: @Kristiyan - There is no need for `parseInt`, here. He is trying to perform the operation inline and already has the integers.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, I know. But if he make other manipulations, which are not poste, this will prevent type conflict.

Comment: @Kristiyan - That will only prevent type conflicts if he has the numbers in string form already, which is not part of the OP.

Comment: It probably doesn't work because you've misnested brackets.  The `}` needs to be inside the `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try:

```
array[0].animate({path:"M, " + (point_1_x + 500) + ", " + point_1_y, 5, '<>');
```

JavaScript is a string-based language, and it is not type safe. You can perform mathematical operations within a statement in which you are concatenating integers into a string by wrapping the operations in parenthesis.

Also note that you did not close the brace you opened before `path:`, so use the following:

```
array[0].animate({path:"M, " + (point_1_x + 500) + ", " + point_1_y, 5, '<>'});
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

use brackets, then it should work:

```
array[0].animate({path:"M, "+ ( point_1_x+500 ) +", "+point_1_y+"", 5, '<>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses :

```
array[0].animate({path:"M, "+(point_1_x+500)+", "+point_1_y+"", 5, '<>');
```